# ruby on rails call a conroller method from view button click and access view html elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My main question is as below:
Below are the files:
routes.rb:

```
get 'service_action/test'       => 'service_actions#show'
post 'service_action/test'      => 'service_actions#test'
```

test.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag("/service_action/test", :method=>"post") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:todo_text) %>
  <%= select_tag(:ddl3, options_for_select([["Windows","1"],["RHEL","2"],["ALL","3"]]), class: 'form-control')%>
  <%= submit_tag("Add todo", :class=>"btn") %>

  <table data-toggle="table" id="instance_list" data-url="data.json" data-height="299" data-click-to-select="true" data-search="true">
      <thead>
      <tr>
          <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true" data-formatter="stateFormatter"></th>
          <th data-field="Name">Machine Name</th>
          <th data-field="DNS Name">DNS Name</th>
          <th data-field="Server Type" data-align="">Server Type</th>
          <th data-field="Platform" data-align="">Platform</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

controller.rb:

```
def test
    `mkdir c:\\opt\\CreateJSON\\#{params[:todo_text]}`
    `mkdir c:\\opt\\CreateJSON\\#{params[:ddl3]}`
    render 'test'
  end
def show
    render 'test'
end
```

My question is: "I can access the textfield(todo_text) and select_tag(ddl3) values in my controller method as you can see, but I am not able to access the selected values from the table included. It is table in which I display some info to user and user select n number of rows from this table. I need the selected rows too from the view back to my controller method."

Please help me on this.

Comment: Which part of the whole application do you have most trouble with? You already have the controller action and the view seems to be almost working. The onclick event can be included in the form_for or as jQuery in the view

Comment: Hi Jean,Thanks for reply. I have updated my question, please reply on the question.

Comment: I am not really familiar with bootstraps tables... Could you post the params your controller receives?

Comment: @Jean-Paul it is part of the form_tag

Comment: Hey Jean, how to do that? How can I add table to the form tag? I searched on google, but found no example for this. Requesting you to provide some info on how to do this. They are selected by a check box on each row.

Comment: @Jean-Paul that was the core of my question. I've googled it and it seems like bootstrap adds a checkbox to each row in the table, but I am not sure what the naming convention is...

Comment: Can you make the table without bootstrap?

Comment: @Jean-Paul yes he could, but it seems to be a neat little feature taking away a lot of work :) and btw, please do not confuse me with OP :)

Comment: Hmm that would be somewhat typical, I am using bootstrap to get check box on each row. Then I need those selected rows' values back into the controller method for processing. I am able to find one example for this as: 'http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#methods/getSelections.html', but not sure how to use this.

Comment: well if you can, please go to your console and watch the incomming request, rails tells you which parameters were sent. we can help you deciphering the output.

Comment: I would suggest using Rails' default form fields, especially form_for instead of form_tag. The checkboxes would be really easy to make. It seems bootstrap table is not easy to manage in Rails. And can you post the complete table? right now there is just the heading/th.

Comment: @Lovelesh it seems like bootstrap will name the checkboxes with 'btSelectItem', which doesn't make much sense for rails, because it will result in a single params[:btSelectItem]... If you can not set the name in the checkbox, this will not work without some javascript and that approach would be everything but clean :(

Comment: Thanks guys for looking into this. Here is what I am feeling about this: 1) When I try to access #{params[:instance_list]}, it gives me blank return. 2) #{params[:btSelectItem]} with no value selected gives me blank. 3) #{params[:btSelectItem]} with one or more value selected gives me "on" in controller. Do you guys extract any info from this?

Comment: Also I am ready to give up bootstrap for table, but do you guys know any tag which can be used for table in ror forms? I didn't found any. Also if there is any solution with jquery or ajax, I am happy for that. I read some where that ajax post is used to do this, but not sure how?

Comment: @Lovelesh you don't need anything special for this, you can make a regular HTML table with a column for the checkboxes. Just use the rails helper checkbox_tag for the content of that column, or even write the html tag yourself and you are golden. The most important thing is the name="something" attribute inside the checkbox-tag, because that determines what rails will make of that param. If you do <input type="checkbox" name="thing" value="true">, rails will show that inside your params hash as :thing => true. But you SHOULD use the rails helper, whenever you can :)

Comment: @Ninigi: Thanks for the info, I am searching a lot on net but not able to find any step by step tutorial, which will show me how to proceed with a table with checkbox and get selected rows back to the controller method. Requesting you to provide an example please.

Comment: Also I came to know that I can also set a hidden field value to selected rows and then can get that hidden field value in controller method, any one know about how to achieve this?

Comment: Please help me on this query.